# asp.net Run Javascript confirm from codebehind with custom text and return if OK selected

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a grid on a page with a list of items - I have a column for tickbox - One use is to remove/delete item.

I have a button "Delete Item" - this runs some code behind to find the item ticked and if only one ticked I would like to ask the user - "Do you want to delete item ABC ... " i.e. showing the text of item selected - If they click OK continue.

I have tried a few options - closest is to use a hidden field to store the value as in below but the code behind goes to the line to read the hidden field before the confirm box comes up so its not going to pick up the value. The confirm box opens OK and message OK.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Confirm(txt) {
        if (confirm(txt)) {
        hdnResultValue = 1
       }
    }
</script>

<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnResultValue" Value="0" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="DelItem" runat="server" Text="Remove Item"/>
```

In code behind

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "myconfirm", "Confirm('" & txtMsg & "');", True)
If hdnResultValue.Value = 1 Then
     'Code to delete
End If
```

Appreciate any ideas on getting this to work or alternatives.

---

Reply to Jon:-

Thanks Jon - I had a go at that but doesn't get the itemname - suspect its because I need to reference the grid - presume rather than "this" I need the gridID but this didn't work either.

Below main part of page:-

In console first log for "this" came up empty. I have the button sitting above the grid not as part of the grid!.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmClick() {
        var itemName;
        itemName = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(2)").text();
        //AS I haven't tested this lets add some debugging
        //Check $(this) exists
        console.log($(this));

        //Check we got a tr
        console.log($(this).closest("tr"));

        //Check we got the target td
        console.log($(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(2)"));

        return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete: " + itemName);
        confirm(txt)
    }
</script>
<div>   
    <asp:Button ID="DelItem" runat="server" Text="Delete Item" OnClientClick="return confirmClick();"/>     
</div>
<asp:GridView ID="ItemList" runat="server">
    <Columns>                        
        <asp:TemplateField >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Select" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>            
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemID" HeaderText="ItemID" Visible="True">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemName" HeaderText="Item Name" Visible="True">
        </asp:BoundField>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Can you provide more info on your grid. Are you using a gridview? Can you put a class on the column with the Item name. If so we can use javascript or even better the jQuery library to get that text value.

Comment: There was a bug in my original code. I fixed that in update 1. Then I realised the button wasn't in the grid. That fix is in update 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probelm with your approach is that by the time your javascript is triggered the page has already been posted back. So then when the client clicks "OK" the page will have to be posted back yet again.

The rule to remember is javascript is executed client side in the browser, vb.net on the server. Also remember that the whole serverside code is executed **before** the page (HTML/CSS/javascript) is returned to the browser. So in your current example the `hdnResultValue.Value = 1` check is going to happen before the javascript is executed, as the page has yet to be sent to the browser.

What you need to do is trigger the javascript before the page is posted back

```
<asp:Button ID="DelItem" runat="server" Text="Remove Item" OnClientClick="return confirmClick(this);"/>
```

Then have your javascript already on the page, I'm going to use the incredibly helpful [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library to get the text for the item:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmClick(itemClicked) {
    var itemName;

    //If you have a class on the colum with the item for this example
    //class="itemName"
    //itemName = $(itemClicked).closest("tr").find(".itemName").text();

    //If you don't have a class you could use the columns index
    //3rd column for this exampl
    //Index is 0 based
    itemName = $(itemClicked).closest("tr").find("td:eq(2)").text(); 

    //AS I haven't tested this lets add some debugging
    //Check $(this) exists
    console.log($(itemClicked));

    //Check we got a tr
    console.log($(itemClicked).closest("tr"));

    //Check we got the target td
    console.log($(itemClicked).closest("tr").find("td:eq(2)"));


    return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete: " + itemName);

 }
</script>
```

Don't forget to include the jQuery library!

Your other option is yo use AJAX for an asynchronous post back to generate the confirm message.

Here's an article outlining how to use the ModalPopUpExtender to use a fancier confirm: http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/confirm_gridview_deletes_with.html.

**Update** A quick bug fix. I forgot to pass through the item bein click. It has been added as a parameter to the javascript function.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r5vV9/) of the script in action

**Update 2** - Get Text of checked row

Change button to (we've taken out the parameter):

```
<asp:Button ID="DelItem" OnClientClick="return confirmClick();" runat="server" Text="Remove Item" />
```

Change your script to

```
function confirmClick() {
    //<%= ItemList.ClientId %> gets the rendered client side ID of your gridview
    var table = $("<%= ItemList.ClientId %>"); 
    var checkedRow = $(table).find("tr").has("input:checked");
    var itemName = $(checkedRow).find("td:eq(2)").text();

   return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete: " + itemName);
}
```

[Script Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r5vV9/2/)

Comment: Thanks Jon. That makes sense as to why not returning. I tried your code and all works OK except not picking up ItemName. I am using a Gridview bound to a datasource. First column in a checkbox (in template) and third column is a BoundField - ItemName - I want to pick up the ItemName for the line that is ticked. I am not using class - happy to use index. Appreciate any further help.

Comment: Jon Thanks - seems to be working OK but still not returning the itemname - I wonder if its to do with the Select row. Does it need to know the tickbox is in column index(0) ? or refer to name "Select". Also I tried refering to table as var table = $("#ItemList"); but no luck.

Comment: Jon I have got this working now - I changed the reference to the grid to - var table = document.getElementById('<%=ItemList.ClientID%>'); This finds it OK and all works perfect now - thanks for your help.

Comment: I dropped the id selector accidentally for the table... I've updated if you want to go more jQuery. It should be `var table = $("#<%= ItemList.ClientId %>");`. Pesky #!

Comment: OK thanks - I have changed to use this - works fine.

Answer (score 0):

To set value of hidden field do

```
document.getElementById("hdnResultValue").value = 1;
```